# How to manually change value of primary key in Django Model through serializers?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

**Is it somehow possible to manually change ID value in AutoField (primary key) through serializer?**
I found this in documentation of Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#auto-incrementing-primary-keys, but I have no idea how to do this including serializers. 
**My task is:** If car with given ID does not exists, fetch car from external API and save it.

Model:

```
from django.db import models

class Car(models.Model):
    speed = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    wheels = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

My serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Car


class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['id', 'speed', 'color', 'wheels']
```

My view:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def car_detail_id(request, id):
    try:
        car = Car.objects.get(pk=id)
    except Car.DoesNotExist:
        #-----------------------------------------------------------#
        car = search_car(id) #fetch car from external API
        if request.method == "GET" and car is not None:
            serializer = CarSerializer(data=car)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------#
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    return car_detail(request, "id", car) #method to handle CRUD
```

Car structure:

```
 {
    "speed": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "color": "Green",
    "wheels": "Black"
  },
```

This implementation fetch car with given ID from API, then saves it, but with different ID.
Are there any better ways to do this? Let me know below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `serializers.ModelSerializer` like your above example `class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):`. You can set extra properties while saving.

```
serializer = CarSerializer(data=car)
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save(id=id)
```

You can add other properties as long as it is in the model. I can't find any other solution to do it.

I found this way from here [Solution](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/04/07/how-to-save-extra-data-to-a-django-rest-framework-serializer.html). Hope this will helps

Answer (score 0):

The AutoField function to build a pk requires a unique identifier and it cannot/should not be changed in the DB (as far as I am aware).

I would focus on accomplishing the use-case another way. You could use try/except to check if the object exists:

```
try:
    ObjectName.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['id'])  # insert correct syntax for your use case
except ObjectName.DoesNotExist:
    # Make external call here
```

Comment: I think we should not change it but the OP wants to set the primary id when creating, not updating.

Answer (score 0):

at first:
You are dont need to create autokey. Django do it automatically.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

at second:
You are save model on GET, it's bad desigion:

- GET for read.
- POST for write.

At last, try to use view and viewsets from DRF, it is easier:

```
class CreatePostAPIView(CreatePostAPIView):
    model=Post
```

You can call this DRF-view everythere:

```
def post_detail_id(request, id):
    ....    
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
            #-----------------------------------------------------------#
            request.data = request.method == "GET" and search_post(id) #fetch 
            if request.data:
                return CreatePostAPIView().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
            #-----------------------------------------------------------#
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

My opinion, somewhere business-logic in post_detail_id is broken.